# How to plot the decision boundary when the feature vectors are letters

Tags: machine-learning, plot, classification

I am doing classification where each sample is a sequence of letters A C T G(a DNA sequence). For example:

Sample 1: A C T G A
Sample 2: C T G A A

How can I plot the decision boundary when my features are discrete?

Comment: How are your converting your sequence of letters into numbers? Then, only we can suggest some solutions for you.

Comment: I use one-hot encoding, for example, A = 1000, C = 0100, T = 0010, G = 0001

Comment: What model are you using?

Comment: I am using Ridge